# How to use Android Studio and Eclipse for the same project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I want to set up an android project so it can be used by android studios and eclipse.
There is no problem in using eclipse project with android studios, you only have to set up the `gradle.build` file.
How can I make an eclipse android project if the project was created in Android studios, or changed/updated in android studios. Is there an easy way, like a gradle command or a plugin function that would create eclipse project to what eclipse has to create android studio project?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655099/one-android-project-for-eclipse-and-android-studio

Comment: This does not seem like a duplicate to me. The OP wants to actively and continuously work on the same project from both IDEs. The "duplicate" shows how to import from one side to another. Anyway, OP here's the answer: start a new project in Eclipse and for the `src` and `res` folder (and the manifest too!) use file **links** to the actual files from the Android Studio project. Basically leave the Android Studio project as is and use only links in the Eclipse project. Thus you can make modifications in one IDE and they will appear in the other one too.